# How to call Action<T> parameter in a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code. The compiler gives

```
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'parameter' of 'SARSystem.WithLock<T>(SARSystem.Locks, Action<T>, T)


public class Locks
{         
    private Locks() {}
    private static object _lock = new object();
    public static object Lock { get { return _lock; } }
}

public static void WithLock<T>(Locks theLock, Action<T> action, T param)
{
    Monitor.Enter(theLock);
    {
        try
        {
            action(param);
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(theLock);
        }
    }
}

private static Locks tradingSystemLock;

public void OnQuote(TickPriceMessage tp)
{
    // How do I call WithLock? This doesn't work.
    WithLock(tradingSystemLock, delegate (TickPriceMessage tpm) { Console.WriteLine(tp.ToString()); });                  
}
```

Comment: `action(anObjectOfTypeT);`

Comment: Thanks, See my edit.

Comment: @Ivan, So? What is new in your edit...?

Comment: Look at the OnQuote function

Comment: Also, your `Monitor.Enter`/`Monitor.Exit`/`try`/`finally` structure can be expressed simply as a `lock` block.

Comment: Yes I know, but making it explicit allows me to have finer grain control

Comment: Also, you are calling `WithLock` which is static from non-static `OnQuote` - I bet compiler tells you that.

Comment: `WithLock` takes 3 parameters and you are only supplying 2. You need to supply an instance of `TickPriceMessage` to `WithLock` (`tp`?). It seems you want `WithLock(tradingSystemLock, delegate (TickPriceMessage m) { Console.WriteLine(m.ToString()); }, tp);`

Comment: Thanks Lee. That was it. Duh. I got confused by the lamda. It is not clean.

Comment: @jjczopek calling static from non-static is fine, the opposite is a problem.

Comment: @Ivan you can write it shorter `WithLock(tradingSystemLock, m => Console.WriteLine(m.ToString()), tp);`

Comment: Ah, that is much cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong with your `Action` call, but with how you call your function:

```
WithLock(tradingSystemLock, 
    delegate (TickPriceMessage tpm) { Console.WriteLine(tp.ToString()); },
    tp);
```

Which would be immediately apparent if you bothered to read/post the error message you got.

As a side note, not only is your `WithLock<>` useless, it's also wrong -- I think you wanted to lock on `theLock.Lock`, not on `theLock`. Understandable, given the descriptive names you give variables.

Comment: More useless things in just one line of code: `.ToString()`, `delegate` and the whole thing after it. Plus you know, your reinventing the wheel instead of using the `lock` keyword, because you seem to think you can do it better.

Comment: Blindy - perhaps Ivan is simply trying to learn how to code? Criticism which informs is then very useful - unfortunately, yours does not. Please try to be less judgmental and more helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Lee comment, your method takes three arguments:

```
WithLock<T>(Locks theLock, Action<T> action, T param)
```

lock, delegate and param.

The following should work:

```
public void OnQuote(TickPriceMessage tp)
{        
    WithLock<TickPriceMessage>(tradingSystemLock, (tpm) => {Console.WriteLine(tpm.ToString());}, tp);                  
}
```